# Select rows where two or more (flags) columns are ON

Tags: mysql, select

I have a table like this:

```
+----+-------+-------+-------+
| Id | Flag1 | Flag2 | Flag3 |
+----+-------+-------+-------+
|  1 |     0 |     0 |     1 |
|  2 |     0 |     0 |     0 |
|  3 |     1 |     1 |     1 |
|  4 |     1 |     1 |     0 |
+----+-------+-------+-------+
```

How can I select the rows which has any two or more flags on?

In this example the query should select rows with Id: `3 and 4`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couldn't you just do this?

```
....
WHERE Flag1 + Flag2 + Flag3 >= 2
```

### [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/51029/2)

**Result**

```
| ID |
------
|  3 |
|  4 |
```